# How to find element for this example using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I need to find an element in this area, but every single time id and name changing, also XPath too. Can't use classes as well cause there is two fields got same classes:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="flightDepartureSearchAutoComplate3-0-69f"]').send_keys('AYT')
```

HTML:

```
<input name="flightDepartureSearchAutoComplate3-0-69f" id="flightDepartureSearchAutoComplate3-0-69f" type="text" ng-model="departureFlightSelectedDestination0" placeholder="From" class="form-control auto-complete ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-editable ng-empty ng-touched" uib-typeahead="departureFlightDestination as departureFlightDestination.label for departureFlightDestination in controller.getDepartureAutocomplete($viewValue,0) | limitTo: 10" typeahead-editable="false" typeahead-wait-ms="750" typeahead-min-length="3" typeahead-append-to="departureTargetElements[0]" typeahead-select-on-blur="true" typeahead-focus-on-select="false" typeahead-select-on-exact="true" typeahead-template-url="flightAutoComplateTypeaheadTemplate.html" typeahead-on-select="controller.departureAutoComplateChanged()" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" b2b-validate="required" data-sln-id="slnTxt_departureFlightAutoComplate" autofocus="" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead-25-8460" style="">
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="flightDepartureSearchAutoComplate3-0-22d"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Comment: How many elements are there on the page that start with flightDepartureSearchAutoComplate  for the id? Is it only one?

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control.auto-complete.ng-valid-editable[id^='flightDepartureSearchAutoComplate'][placeholder='From']"))).send_keys('AYT')
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control auto-complete ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-editable ng-empty ng-touched' and starts-with(@id, 'flightDepartureSearchAutoComplate')][@placeholder='From']"))).send_keys('AYT')
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Why Angular element implies inducing WebDriverWait?

Comment: @MateMrše Angular element implies those are created/modified by _JavaScript_ and/or _AJAX Calls_. So _WebDriverWait_ is inevitable in order to interact with those elements.

Comment: @DebanjanB According to your recommend i have errors below

 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Its solved, with:

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="From"]').send_keys('AYT')